# AWS Lambda function update command showing environment variables

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables

I'm using gitlab pipelines to update configuration and code of my AWS Lambda functions. I noticed that when you perform AWS cli requests to update the Lambda like:

`aws lambda update-function-configuration --region $your_region --function-name $your_lambda_arn --handler $your_lambda_handler --runtime $your_lambda_runtime`

OR

`aws lambda update-function-code --region $your_region --function-name $your_lambda_arn --s3-bucket $your_s3_bucket --s3-key $your_project_name.zip`

Both requests responses in gitlab console reveals the environment variables (like db connection string) and I would like to keep it secret. Is there any way, any flag or whatsoever to keep these values hidden in response?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could perhaps use `jq` to exclude the output? Otherwise use an SDK (e.g. boto3 or aws-sdk-go) and don't print the entire response.

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/Me.json
{
    "FunctionName": "my-function",
    "LastModified": "2019-09-26T20:28:40.438+0000",
    "RevisionId": "e52502d4-9320-4688-9cd6-152a6ab7490d",
    "MemorySize": 256,
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/my-function-role-uy3l9qyq",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "Runtime": "nodejs10.x",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "Environment": {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "CodeSha256": "5tT2qgzYUHaqwR716pZ2dpkn/0J1FrzJmlKidWoaCgk=",
    "Description": "",
    "VpcConfig": {
        "SubnetIds": [],
        "VpcId": "",
        "SecurityGroupIds": []
    },
    "CodeSize": 304,
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:my-function",
    "Handler": "index.handler"
}

# no Environment key
$ cat ~/Desktop/Me.json | jq 'del(.Environment)'
{
  "FunctionName": "my-function",
  "LastModified": "2019-09-26T20:28:40.438+0000",
  "RevisionId": "e52502d4-9320-4688-9cd6-152a6ab7490d",
  "MemorySize": 256,
  "Version": "$LATEST",
  "Role": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/my-function-role-uy3l9qyq",
  "Timeout": 3,
  "Runtime": "nodejs10.x",
  "TracingConfig": {
    "Mode": "PassThrough"
  },
  "CodeSha256": "5tT2qgzYUHaqwR716pZ2dpkn/0J1FrzJmlKidWoaCgk=",
  "Description": "",
  "VpcConfig": {
    "SubnetIds": [],
    "VpcId": "",
    "SecurityGroupIds": []
  },
  "CodeSize": 304,
  "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:my-function",
  "Handler": "index.handler"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found two additional solutions for that case:

1. Gitlab itself has mechanism of hiding secrets, to achieve that you can setup environment variable in gitlab cicd settings as protected, in that case console output should be hidden where needed
2. You can filter out the aws cli response
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html

Regards